# Log4j perfomance and object creation

Tags: java, logging

I have a question about perfomance with **log4j** logs, In my project, I see a lot of log messages in the classes. In production environment, the log not print many of these (The normal behaivour). Anyway, each log is creating a **String** object. Example:

```
Log.debug("This my debug message 1");
...
Log.debug("This my debug message 400");
```

We have a lot of String literals created for logs. Can this affect considerably to my production site, even if I only show error level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can, if constructing the log string is fairly complex (e.g. calling a complicated `toString` on an object).

In your case (simple string logging) it's probably not worth writing a guard:

```
if (Log.isDebugEnabled()) {
   Log.debug("...");
}
```

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html ("Performance" section at the bottom)

Comment: OP is speaking about _string literals_, although your hint is correct.

Comment: That's the reason why most newer log frameworks (e.g. Log4J 2.x) allow format template style messages: `logger.debug("Entry number: {} is {}", i, entry[i]);`. If you can generate your log message that way, that's probably the way to go (less clutter - still one line of code).

Comment: using a guard for a simple log statement does not make sense. When the log is inactive you just replace one method call for another, when the log is active you do two calls instead of one.

Comment: @Hanry True, but drkicknrush is talking about complicated toString() methods where a guard does actually make sense. While the OP is writing of string literals, he might still have expensive toString() methods...

Comment: Using a guard may make sense for messages that consume a lot of time and resources to construct. But the standard Java API's `java.util.logging.Logger` has come a long way and in Java 8 there is a [log(Level, Supplier)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) method that makes guards unnecessary and makes the code more readable. Shame the current versions of major third-party logging systems haven't done that.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Something learned, didn't know this new method. Unfortunately, the question is targeted specifically at log4j - this leaves only the format template style or traditional guards.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed string literal is no problem, there is no runtime overhead associated with that (apart from the method call itself).

A different case are constructed messages like `"user: " + user`. The string concatenation will be done even if the log is not active.

Answer (score 0):

It's a performance question and that basically boils down to: **measure it!**
We don't know how many "a lot" log messages are, how expensive your other code is etc. Too many factors to give a well founded answer.

I think the general understanding is that **in most cases** reasonable log statements **should not affect performance measurably** and that it's cheaper to use faster hardware than have a developer remove log statements. But that might not cover your specific case.

Logging can get a lot more expensive if the log message is **not a literal** but a generated string (string concatenation or a complex `toString()`-method.) For extensive information, look at the **performance section of the manual** for [log4j 1.x.](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#performance) or [log4j 2.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html).

Removing log statements might be a case of [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization), though it is never wrong to try to **minimize the overhead** (at least in critical sections). In log4J this can be done (as suggested):

- using format template style messages (available since log4j 2.0):

  ```
  logger.debug("Entry number: {} is {}", i, entry[i]);
  ```
- using guards

  ```
  if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug(expensiveMethodReturningLogString());
  }
  ```